# Unable to connect to Indy pool from webserver

Tags: docker, hyperledger-indy, docker-command

I have a running indy_pool docker container with 4 nodes. I followed the article https://medium.com/@smaldeniya/setup-hyperledger-indy-pool-in-local-linux-environment-using-docker-304d13eb86dc to do this setup.

Now, trying to create a webserver docker container, in which I am facing issue to connect with indy_pool using the pool_transactions_genesis. Getting the below error

[image: Screenshot from 2023-07-14 18-52-41]

Attaching the docker-compose which I used to bring up the webserver.

[docker-compose.txt](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/files/12050889/docker-compose.txt)

I tried using the client ip and node ip as indy_pool docker-container ip address which is 172.0.1.2. But, facing same error.

Can anyone pls let me know how to connect the indy_pool from webserver? Thanks in Advance.